# no newline in echo/printf in BASH while loop

Tags: bash, while-loop, printf, echo, newline

why on executing following script each printf (tried also with echo) is printed on the same line??

```
function read_dom () {
    local IFS=\>
    read -d \< ENTITY CONTENT
}

cat my_xml_file.xml | \
{   while read_dom; do
        printf "(entity:content %s:%s)" $ENTITY $CONTENT
}
```

Now, this produces a single line output:

```
(entity:content member:)(entity:content name:id)(entity:content /name:)
```

How do I change this to multiline, like:

```
(entity:content member:)
(entity:content name:id)
(entity:content /name:)
```

Comment: `printf` isn't `echo`.  You need `\n`.

Comment: `printf "(entity:content %s:%s)\n" $ENTITY $CONTENT`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll just need to add the newline character, `\n`,  to the `printf` statement:

```
printf "(entity:content %s:%s)\n" $ENTITY $CONTENT
```

Answer (score 5):

`printf` doesn't append a newline as standard behaviour, you need to add it to your print string:

```
printf "(entity:content %s:%s)\n" $ENTITY $CONTENT
```